# Difference between terminado and terminó

Tags: participio

Okay, so I have this sentence:

```
Cuando La Segunda Guerra Mundial había terminado...
```

I think this translates to:

```
When World War II had ended...
```

I want to know the difference between these:

```
había terminado (had ended)
terminó (ended)
```

Also, should I be using `hubo`?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You just mentioned the difference: one is 'had ended' and the other is 'ended'.

Answer (score 0):

**TERMINADO** (EJEMPLOS - EXAMPLES)

. -No conecte la unidad al suministro de corriente sin haber TERMINADO de armarla.

. -Do not connect to power supply until assembly is COMPLETE.

**TERMINÓ** (EJEMPLOS - EXAMPLES)

. -Su mandato TERMINÓ en 1999 con infinitos escándalos de corrupción y una recesión económica.

. -His mandate ENDED in 1999 amid a vast array of corruption scandals and an economic recession.